# how do I print a title for the top of my running program to continuously be visible for a code that prints and runs an endless amount of data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example: (to stay visible on the running program, able to view it at anytime if needed to scroll to the top)

```
print("this is my title")

print("here is my sub title")

count = 0
while count < 5000:
    print("hello")
    count = count + 1  # or count += 1
```

My code runs for as long as I set it too, that's not the problem. But when the program runs, it never shows the top printed title, or if I were to stop the program for a moment and physically scroll to the top, that printed title and other various text isn't visible.

How do I fix this to where, even if I wanted to print a million items, I could still see the printed title and printed information at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First a useful non python way:

If you run a script (say my_long_print_script.py) from the terminal you can use `less` (in linux and osx for sure):

```
python my_long_print_script.py | less
```

then use `enter` to scroll down and `q` to quit.

## Writing to stdout in python

In python you can directly write to stdout and 'overwrite' your previous output. This can lead to some sort of progress bar behaviour, I'm not sure this is what you want, here is an example:

```
# content of my_long_print_script.py:
import sys
from time import sleep
sys.stdout.write('This title should stay\n')
sys.stdout.write('this subtitle too\n')
for count in xrange(100):
    sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('{0}\r'.format(count))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

When you run this as a script (so you type `python my_very_long_print_script.py` in the terminal) the two title lines will persist and below a single line will continuously be updated.

FYI: I added the `sleep` because the count changes too quickly otherwise.

Hope this was somehow useful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use python's [curses library](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html). This is how you create "windows" that can be redrawn in-place.

I wrote a CLI version of 2048 that would scroll the terminal every time I output the game's board after a move. Using curses, I can now just overwrite the previous board without any scrolling.

Basically you'll want to initialize a new curses window object, set your output string to "My Title Here" and issue a window.redraw() command at (0,0) every time your program iterates.